# Flutter - Run function after showDialog is dismissed

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I do have an app that creates a AlertDialog when a certain amount of points are reached. In this AlertDialog I added a button that should reset the points. But I do not know how to run a function after the AlertDialog is dismissed.It would be great if somebody could help me with this problem.

With this code I call the AlertDialog:

```
Future<Null> gewinner(int gewinner_team, List<String> spieler){
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return GewinnerDialog(gewinner_team,spieler);
        }
    );
  }
```

And this is my code that creates the UI of the AlertDialog:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'spieler_definieren.dart';

class GewinnerDialog extends StatefulWidget{
  int gewinner_team;
  List<String> spieler;

  GewinnerDialog(this.gewinner_team, this.spieler);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _Gewinner(gewinner_team, spieler);
}

class _Gewinner extends State<GewinnerDialog>{
  int gewinner_team;
  List<String> spieler;

  _Gewinner(this.gewinner_team, this.spieler);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      content: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Text("Winner")
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        //this FlatButton should reset all the points, that are saved into a List<String>
        // in another class
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.replay),
                new Text("New Game") 

              ],
            )
        ),
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new SpielerDefinieren()));
            },
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.person_add),
                new Text("New Player")
              ],
            )
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me with this problem XD

Answer (score 51, accepted):

showDialog() can await a callback, and Navigator.pop can pass a value back.  so instead of:

```
Future<Null> gewinner(int gewinner_team, List<String> spieler){
   return showDialog(
       ....
   );
}
```

you can use:

```
Future<Null> gewinner(int gewinner_team, List<String> spieler) async {
   String returnVal = await showDialog(
       ....
   );
}
```

and then in the dialog builder/screen you simply pop with a return value:

```
Navigator.pop(context, 'success');
```

and then do with the `returnVal` what you wish.

```
if (returnVal == 'success') {
  ...
}
```

if the dialog is dismissed then `returnVal` will be null.

Comment: Thanks. you saved me ( as pdf )

Comment: You made my day :D

Comment: And the most important part of your answer was for me "and then in the dialog builder/screen you simply pop with a return value:" - because I couldn't understand how to send "a return value"  - thanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the simple example of getting status from Alert Dialog

```
    RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        title: Text('Are you sure?'),
                        content: Text('Do you want to remove item?'),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('Success'),
                              child: Text('NO')),
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('Failure'),
                              child: Text('YES'))
                        ],
                      )).then((value) =>
                  print('Result: ' + value.toString()));
            },
            child: Text('Show Alert Dialog'),
          ),
```

Comment: What if user just taps out of `Dialog` and dismissed it..how can the function be invoked..with a particular value..!?

Comment: @srikanth7785: It would be definitely null and it should be